# node.js - Emit events from an object

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, module, eventemitter

I have the following module in node.js:

```
var obj = {};
obj.prop1 = "value1";
obj.prop2 = "value2";

asyncFunction(function(data) {
     obj.prop3 = data;
     // I would like to do: obj.emit("completed");
});

module.exports = obj;
```

So I can import it like:

```
var imp = require('./obj');

imp.on("completed", function() {
     console.log("Hello!");
});
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to make `obj` an `EventEmitter`.  This can be done pretty simply - just change this:

```
var obj = {};
```

To this:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var obj = new EventEmitter();
```

Comment: If you need to make a *class* that is EventEmitter, it is spelled out in [this article](http://howtonode.org/demystifying-events-in-node).

Comment: You can do that if you want, but it's not strictly required. You can create generic EventEmitters and interact with them through the usual `on` and `emit` API methods.

Comment: Oops.. just saw the "If". I thought you were making an assertion that it was necessary. So yes, fully agree with that statement :)

Comment: A very similar example from the Node.js docs http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports

Comment: I think you need to remove the parenthesis from the EventEmitter like: var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

Comment: Instead of using the Eventemitter as a constructor, you should "inherit" the properties with nodes util.inherits, like so: `require('util').inherits(Constructor, events.EventEmitter);`

Comment: @OlliK His code example seems to indicate there is only one instance of `obj`, so what would be the advantages of building a custom constructor?